# How to insert Text into Textboxes created during runtime (WFA)

Tags: c#

I want to insert text into textboxes creating during run time
user can decide how many textboxes will create (range 1-99) I am using this code to create textboxes

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Calculation.Num; i++)
        {

            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "txtBox" + i;
            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 50 + (20 * i) * 2);
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);              


        }
```

Suppose user create 5 textboxes it will look like this

[image: Form with 5 Textboxes]

after that user insert numbers in each textbox then click calculate then all numbers stored in array using this code

```
            Button btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn.Name.Equals("btn1"))
        {
            var sum = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                .Where(t => char.IsDigit(t.Name.Reverse().Take(1).FirstOrDefault())
                    && t.Enabled)
                .Select(t =>
                {
                    double i;
                    if (!double.TryParse(t.Text, out i)) { return 0d; }

                    NumbersHolder[abc] = i;                       
                    abc++;                        

                    return i;
                })
                .Sum();

        }
```

after that i want to calculate those numbers if number is between 70-76 replace that number with 2.75 if it is between 77-79 replace it with 3.0 if it is between 80-86 replace with 3.3 and if it is 87-100 replace with 4.0

Comment: This looks like something you should be using a grid control for, instead of creating up to 100 controls during runtime.

Comment: you mean data grid? i am creating GPA calculator so i think textboxes are best

Answer (score 0):

A little confused by what you are asking.
You want the TextBox controls you are generating in the for loop to have values?

Just set

```
txtRun.Text = "your value";
```

before adding it.

Comment: No i want to create blank textbox then user enter number into textbox i want that number and convert to GPA then replace GPA with user entred number